# No EC2 meta data available while using spring boot to connect to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-regions

While am trying to connect AWS using sprint boot I am facing below error.

After investigated I have understand, while using local we need to give **region** details also in application local properties but still am facing below error.

Here is my code:

[image]

[image]

> There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
> 2022-04-01 16:12:24.992  INFO 70693 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

Below the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver.BEAN_NAME': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonCloudFormation' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.rnd.aws.AwsApplication.main(AwsApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amazonCloudFormation' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
```

Comment: That looks like a generic warning from the SDK and shouldn't matter if you have manually set region. Is there an issue you are having?

Comment: Hi @jordanm ,have set region but spring boot application is not coming up .Terminate my application

Comment: Terminates with what error? the one you have posted is not fatal. Is there a stack trace?

Comment: I have added the error log  to the question ,Please guide me

Comment: @jordanm I have added the error log to the question